# Concatenate 2 NSAttributedString

Tags: ios, swift, nsattributedstring

I am trying to concatenate 2 NSAttributedString. But its giving me error that the method is not available, whereas the method is available. Here is my code:

```
let def = "I am using here <ul><li>Coffee</li><li>Tea</li><li>Milk</li></ul> <br/> <a href='http://www.w3schools.com'>Visit W3Schools.com</a>"

    do {

        definition.delegate = self
        definition.editable = false

        let str = try NSAttributedString(data: def.dataUsingEncoding(NSUnicodeStringEncoding, allowLossyConversion: true)!, options: [ NSDocumentTypeDocumentAttribute: NSHTMLTextDocumentType], documentAttributes: nil)

        let textAttachment = NSTextAttachment()
        textAttachment.image = UIImage(named: "clip_image002.jpg")

        let str2 = NSAttributedString(attachment: textAttachment)

        str.appendAttributedString(str2)

        definition.attributedText = str


    } catch {
        print(error)
    }
```

Basically **str.appendAttributedString(str2)** is generating error. What I am missing?

Comment: use NSMutableAttributedString instead

Answer (score 3):

You aren't allowed to mutate the content of an `NSAttributedString`, you have to  define the string you're appending to as mutable:

```
let str = NSMutableAttributedString()
```

[NSMutableAttributedString](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSMutableAttributedString_Class/)

Comment: does the constructor throw an error or why is there a `try`?

Comment: oh.. didn't catch that when copy-pasting. No, the constructor doesn't throw anything.